# Xamarin.Forms Android app crashes when debugging on Galazy S8 (Exynos)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to debug a `Xamarin.Forms` app which crashes with error

```
BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

on my `Galaxy S8`, however the app does not crash when running on an emulator or when ran on a `One Plus 3t`.

The crash occurs when clicking the menu button on a `Master.Detail` Page.

Any insights in to this would be appreciated as I cannot seem to find any information on this.

Comment: Is there any code associated with clicking the menu button?

Comment: No it is only using the default behaviour of the built in MasterDetail page.